# Can I copy Firefox cookies and Flash cookies from Windows to use in Ubuntu ?

Tags: firefox, windows, flash, cookie

Can I copy Firefox cookies and Flash cookies from Windows to use in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2):

- Firefox cookies are stored in a [`sqlite`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sqlite#Use_in_web_browsers) format, in `cookies.sqlite`, at your [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder)).
- Flash cookies are stored in the [`LSO`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object) format, at [these locations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object#File_locations).

Both formats are OS-independent, so you should be able to migrate them without problems.

Comment: Please add step by step process for beginers

Comment: That's mounting the filesystem of Windows, then copying the directory's content from the paths as linked in my answer (Windows > Linux, and reverse). For the given paths, it's trivial to copy the files from a Windows filesystem to a Linux filesystem. If anything else is unclear, feel free to ask for more details.